# Is it possible to write a universal (for the client and for the server) function to get the absolute path? How to do it?

Tags: php

If I write like this:

```
define('ROOT', $_SERVER["REQUEST_SCHEME"] . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

then when using the server-side function, for example, imagejpeg, an error occurs:

```
imagejpeg(http://mysite/files/users/imgs/original/man.jpg): failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections
```

If I write like this:

```
define('ROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Then in the view (MVC) the picture simply will not open. For example, here is the code:

```
<div style="background-image:url('D:\1Develop\domains\mysite\files/users/imgs/original/man.jpg')"></div>
```

The block with "background-image" is empty. However, if you take the path that is in the url, and paste it into the address bar, the picture will open.

Is it possible to write a universal function that will work on both the client side and the server side?

If that, here's the php function that the path returns:

```
return DOCROOT . 'files/users/imgs/original/' . $user->photo;
```

Comment: its the browser  getting the image, it does not have access to your server, you have to provide a web accessible URL

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible. URLs are not paths; paths are not URLs. Use two different constants for the filesystem root and the URL root.

Comment: There will be more than two constants. Because the way is not alone. Not to one folder. Different constants for the server and for the client - is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a basename url

```
<?php
function basename_url(){
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
        $protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https" : "http";
    }
    else{
        $protocol = 'http';
    }
    $base_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $protocol . "://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$base_url;
};
```

you can remove the file name thou
its from stackoverflow as well but cannt remember the author.